# How to create checkbox in forms for many to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a many to many association and totally confused on how to create checkboxes.

model: lodge.rb

```
    has_many :lodge_facilities, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :facilities, through: :lodge_facilities, :dependent => :destroy    
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :facilities
```

model: lodge_facility.rb

```
belongs_to :lodge
belongs_to :facility
```

model: facility.rb

```
    has_many :lodge_facilities, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :facilities, through: :lodge_facilities, :dependent => :destroy
```

in my form i tried

```
<%= form_for @lodge, :class =>'lodge_form', url: admins_lodge_path, method: :put,:html => {:multipart => true} do |f|%>
<%= f.fields_for :lodge_facilities do |fac| %>
    <%= fac.check_box :ac %>
    <%= fac.label :ac,'AC' %>
    <%= fac.check_box :wifi %>
    <%= fac.label :ac,'Wifi' %>
<% end %>
```

this displays checkbox but when i submit the form in my console i see `Unpermitted parameters: lodge_facilities`
In my controller i have added

```
def lodge_params     
 params.require(:lodge).permit(lodge_facilities_attributes:[:id,:lodge_id,:lodge_facility_id],facilities_attributes: [:id,:ac,:wifi,:internet,:bar,:restaurant,:gym,:pool,:laundry,:parking,:transportation] )
      end
```

What am i missing?

Comment: try this in permit `lodge_facilities:[:id,:lodge_id,:lodge_facility_id]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
    def lodge_params     
 params.require(:lodge).permit(lodge_facilities_attributes:[:id,:lodge_id,:lodge_facility_id],lodge_facilities: [:id,:ac,:wifi,:internet,:bar,:restaurant,:gym,:pool,:laundry,:parking,:transportation] )
      end
```

also you can use nested_form gem

https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form